# Recreate example chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm just starting out with d3, and I want to recreate this connected scatter plot chart:

[image: connected scatter plot]

I don't know how to make the tooltip appear on hover along the y-axis --> like in the example.
I made the basic chart but can't find a solution for the grouped y-axis values.

This is as far as I got:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = { top: 10, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 30 },
  width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3
  .select(".container")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", `0 0 750 500`)
  //.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  //.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

//Read the data
d3.csv(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VladGirboan/Point2/main/Test.csv"
).then(function (data) {
  // List of groups (here I have one group per column)
  const allGroup = ["valueA", "valueB", "valueC", "valueD", "valueE"];

  // Reformat the data: we need an array of arrays of {x, y} tuples
  const dataReady = allGroup.map(function (grpName) {
    // .map allows to do something for each element of the list
    return {
      name: grpName,
      values: data.map(function (d) {
        return { time: d.time, value: +d[grpName] };
      })
    };
  });
  // I strongly advise to have a look to dataReady with
  // console.log(dataReady)

  // A color scale: one color for each group
  const myColor = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])
    .range(["#F98600", "#00BA34", "#0085FF", "#8367C7", "#FDB137"]);

  // Add X axis --> it is a date format
  const x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([2019, 2022]).range([50, width]);
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(4, "").tickPadding(5))
    .attr("font-family", "Montserrat")
    .attr("color", "#969696");

  d3.select("x.axis .tick:first-child").remove();

  // Add Y axis
  const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([height, 0]);
  svg
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .attr("font-family", "Montserrat")
    .attr("color", "#969696");

  // Add the lines
  const line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => x(+d.time))
    .y((d) => y(+d.value));
  svg
    .selectAll("myLines")
    .data(dataReady)
    .join("path")
    .attr("d", (d) => line(d.values))
    .attr("stroke", (d) => myColor(d.name))
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", "none");

  // create a tooltip
  const tooltip = d3
    .select(".container")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "#fafafa");

  // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
  const mouseover = function (event, d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 1);
  };
  const mousemove = function (event, d) {
    tooltip
      .html("Value: " + d.value + "<br/>" + "Year: " + d.time)
      .style("left", `${event.layerX + 10}px`)
      .style("top", `${event.layerY}px`);
  };
  const mouseleave = function (event, d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  };

  // Add the points
  svg
    // First we need to enter in a group
    .selectAll("myDots")
    .data(dataReady)
    .join("g")
    .style("fill", (d) => myColor(d.name))
    // Second we need to enter in the 'values' part of this group
    .selectAll("myPoints")
    .data((d) => d.values)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", (d) => x(d.time))
    .attr("cy", (d) => y(d.value))
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", 0)
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Add a legend at the end of each line

  svg
    .selectAll("myLabels")
    .data(dataReady)
    .join("g")
    .append("text")
    .datum((d) => {
      return { name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1] };
    }) // keep only the last value of each time series
    .attr(
      "transform",
      (d) => `translate(${x(d.value.time)},${y(d.value.value)})`
    ) // Put the text at the position of the last point
    .attr("x", 12) // shift the text a bit more right
    .text((d) => d.name)
    .style("font-family", "Montserrat")
    .style("fill", (d) => myColor(d.name))
    .style("font-size", "16");
});
```

```css
text {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 750px;
}
.tooltip {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Can anyone please help out with this?

Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is getting the data for all the variables based on the `time`, and sorted by `value`:

```
const thisData = dataReady.map(e => ({
    name: e.name,
    value: e.values.find(f => f.time === d.time).value
})).sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
```

Then, you generate a string which you pass to the `html()` method:

```
dataString = thisData.map(e => `${e.name}: ${e.value}`).join("<br>");
tooltip.html(dataString)
```

Also, it's a better idea doing this on `mouseover` instead of `mousemove`.

Here's your code with those changes:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3
  .select(".container")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", `0 0 750 500`)
  //.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  //.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

//Read the data
d3.csv(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VladGirboan/Point2/main/Test.csv"
).then(function(data) {
  // List of groups (here I have one group per column)
  const allGroup = ["valueA", "valueB", "valueC", "valueD", "valueE"];

  // Reformat the data: we need an array of arrays of {x, y} tuples
  const dataReady = allGroup.map(function(grpName) {
    // .map allows to do something for each element of the list
    return {
      name: grpName,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          time: d.time,
          value: +d[grpName]
        };
      })
    };
  });
  // I strongly advise to have a look to dataReady with
  // console.log(dataReady)

  // A color scale: one color for each group
  const myColor = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])
    .range(["#F98600", "#00BA34", "#0085FF", "#8367C7", "#FDB137"]);

  // Add X axis --> it is a date format
  const x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([2019, 2022]).range([50, width]);
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(4, "").tickPadding(5))
    .attr("font-family", "Montserrat")
    .attr("color", "#969696");

  d3.select("x.axis .tick:first-child").remove();

  // Add Y axis
  const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([height, 0]);
  svg
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .attr("font-family", "Montserrat")
    .attr("color", "#969696");

  // Add the lines
  const line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => x(+d.time))
    .y((d) => y(+d.value));
  svg
    .selectAll("myLines")
    .data(dataReady)
    .join("path")
    .attr("d", (d) => line(d.values))
    .attr("stroke", (d) => myColor(d.name))
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", "none");

  // create a tooltip
  const tooltip = d3
    .select(".container")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("background-color", "#fafafa");

  // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
  const mouseover = function(event, d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 1);
    const thisData = dataReady.map(e => ({
        name: e.name,
        value: e.values.find(f => f.time === d.time).value
      })).sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value),
      dataString = thisData.map(e => `${e.name}: ${e.value}`).join("<br>");
    tooltip.html(dataString)
      .style("left", `${event.layerX + 10}px`)
      .style("top", `${event.layerY}px`);
  };
  const mouseleave = function(event, d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  };

  // Add the points
  svg
    // First we need to enter in a group
    .selectAll("myDots")
    .data(dataReady)
    .join("g")
    .style("fill", (d) => myColor(d.name))
    // Second we need to enter in the 'values' part of this group
    .selectAll("myPoints")
    .data((d) => d.values)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", (d) => x(d.time))
    .attr("cy", (d) => y(d.value))
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", 0)
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

  // Add a legend at the end of each line

  svg
    .selectAll("myLabels")
    .data(dataReady)
    .join("g")
    .append("text")
    .datum((d) => {
      return {
        name: d.name,
        value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
      };
    }) // keep only the last value of each time series
    .attr(
      "transform",
      (d) => `translate(${x(d.value.time)},${y(d.value.value)})`
    ) // Put the text at the position of the last point
    .attr("x", 12) // shift the text a bit more right
    .text((d) => d.name)
    .style("font-family", "Montserrat")
    .style("fill", (d) => myColor(d.name))
    .style("font-size", "16");
});
```

```css
text {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 750px;
}

.tooltip {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

PS: I'm not sure if you're asking about grouping the values (what I did) or about making the tooltip showing up when you hover over any empty part of the chart.